# Why is setting a method to have a side_effect causing construction of that method's class to throw?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I'm trying to create an MVCE for another problem I'm having. But I ran into an intermediate problem. You should be able to see and run an MVCE [here](https://trinket.io/python3/f5e6dfe9d9), but here it is laid out:

**B** is just a class that you can call **go()** on, which in turn just prints that it happened.

```
# module_b.py

class B:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.x = True
    print("B constructed OK")
  def go(self):
    print("called B.go()")
```

**A** is a class that holds an instance of B. It also has a **go()** method, which calls the B instance's go() method.

```
# module_a.py

from module_b import B

class A:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    try:
      self.b = B()
      print("A constructed OK")
    except Exception as e:
      print("A's constructor threw an exception: " + repr(e))
  def go(self):
    try:
      self.b.go()
    except Exception as e:
      print("a.go() threw an exception: " + repr(e))
```

And here's the test code:

```
# main.py

from module_a import A
from module_b import B
from unittest import mock
  
@mock.patch("module_a.B")
@mock.patch("module_a.B.go")
def test_b_method_go_throws_1(
    mock_b: mock.Mock,
    mock_b_go: mock.Mock
    ):
  mock_b.return_value = mock.Mock()
  mock_b_go.side_effect = Exception("test") # <-- This line seems to cause the issue.
  a = A()
  a.go()

print("-- test_b_method_go_throws_1() --")
test_b_method_go_throws_1()
print("")
```

Finally, here's the output:

```
-- test_b_method_go_throws_1() --
A's constructor threw an exception: Exception('test')
a.go() threw an exception: AttributeError("'A' object has no attribute 'b'")
```

Originally I was trying to patch an instance's method to throw an error—I'm pretty sure I wasn't doing that right. But here I'm trying to understand why setting `mock_b_go.side_effect` is causing the construction of B to throw an exception.

Comment: Your decorators are in the wrong order. Try `print`ing `mock_b` and `mock_b_go` within `test_b_method_go_throws_1`.

Comment: Looking a little closer, you probably just want `@mock.patch("module_b.B.go")` and can remove `mock_b.return_value = mock.Mock()` since you're only testing the method.

Comment: @Axe319 - Oh my god. It makes sense that the decorators are applied bottom up but it didn't occur to me until you mentioned it. I wonder if this will solve my original problem too. Thanks!

Comment: I am closing this question as I doubt it will be very useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: I'd suggest just deleting it, if it's not actually answerable.